# Executing from a java program from .bat with JFrame and console

Tags: java, swing, batch-file

I have a little problem. I have a java program that when it starts creates a JFrame and in another thread a process execute. This last process uses "System.out.println" to log messages to standard output. I want to execute this java program and see the JFrame but not the console. I want the log of the other process go to a file. I wrote this instruction in the .bat file:

```
start javaw -jar InterceptorProcess.jar > logger.log 2>&1
```

But, it doesn't work. I see the JFrame, the another process is running but the messages don't go to "logger.log". What change do i have to do in the bat? Maybe is impossible without change the java program.

Regards!

This is the java program's code:

```
public class InterceptorProcess 
{


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    FrameInterceptor frame = new FrameInterceptor();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("HELLO!");
    Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
    frame.setIconImage(icon);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("HELLO WORLD!");
}
}
```

Comment: If you start another process and don't redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` of that process, it won't be captured in the output of your java program. It becomes its own process with its own IO pipes at that point.

Comment: @Ryan J, the another process is a Thread. The code is into the ".jar" file too.

Comment: Your OP says "...and in another thread a process execute." I read that as "I'm executing a process in another thread." What "process" are you executing? Also, post some code so we can see it please.

Comment: It should be easy for you to quickly create and post one or two small programs that illustrates your problem for us.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I expressed myself wrong (i am not a native speaker). I think the code is not relevant here. Suppose is a simple "JFrame" and after the instruction "System.out.println("Hola Mundo").

Comment: Until you know the source of your problems and its solution (and if you did, you wouldn't be here), the code is always relevant.

Comment: What about the code that generates the background thread, process, etc?

Comment: Forget the thread. The example i just wrote in the question doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you are redirecting the output of the `start` command to the log file, not the java program. The `start` command isn't actually producing any output, so your log file is empty.

If you omit the `start` command from your batch file and just use the `javaw ...` command, the log file contains the proper content.

For your purposes, I don't think the `start` command is even needed.

You can enable the redirection of your command using `start` by adding the `/B` switch to the command, which essentially won't create a new window to start the process. It has the limitation that the shell will no longer terminate the application on `Ctrl+C`, but your application can handle it if necessary.

From `start` help:

> B
>
> ```
>       Start application without creating a new window. The
>       application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
>       enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
>       the application.
> ```

Change your command to:

```
start /B javaw -jar InterceptorProcess.jar > logger.log 2>&1
```

and you should get the right log contents.

Comment: Hello @Ryan, if i don't use "start" and only "javaw.." the console shows itself.

Comment: @Nico How are you executing your script? Double click in the explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Although Ryan's answer explained the cause of the problem, he didn't explained the solution:

```
start javaw -jar InterceptorProcess.jar ^> logger.log 2^>^&1
```

or

```
start "" "javaw -jar InterceptorProcess.jar > logger.log 2>&1"
```

Comment: Hello @Aacini, thanks for the answer, but i could not fix the problem. Your first command works but the "logger.log" is not written, thus, it has the same comportment than my original command. Your second command gives an error: "Windows can't found the file "javaw -jar InterceptorProcess.jar > logger.log 2>&1". Make sure the name is correctly written and try again".

Answer (score -1):

You explicitly say "I want to execute this java program and see the JFrame but not the console".

Maybe what you are trying to do is just launch a .jar in a way that does not show the console?   If so, as long as you create the executable .jar  the correct way:

```
Create a manifest file and your jar file:
C:\mywork> echo Main-Class: InterceptorProcess >manifest.txt
C:\mywork> jar cvfm InterceptorProcess.jar manifest.txt *.class
or
C:\mywork> jar cvfe InterceptorProcess.jar InterceptorProcess *.class
```

and [as long as your Windows file assocation for .jar is ok](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/4144970), then it will launch without a shell if you double click on it.

Comment: Hello @djangofan. Thanks for the answer, but Ryan J's solution was what i was looking for.